# remove spaces between grids in gridview

Tags: java, android

I want to remove any spaces between the grids of columns or rows in Gridview.Any help will be appreciated.

here is my gridview in xml file

```
   <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0px"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"></GridView>
```

here is my everycell.xml file.Hope this will help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
>


<ImageView
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove vertical spacing

Comment: tried columnWidth = "wrap_content"?

Comment: use try and error method. alter all the attr which u think defines property of each cell and chck the results... Because for me, by default it was showing no space between cells

Comment: change this properties value : android:stretchMode="none"

Comment: @haresh this isn't working also.

Comment: have you shown image on GridView then please set this properties : android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: I have posted the entire xml now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a background color for your RelativeLayout inside your row item xml. You should see that there's no space between the grid items.

Comment: Yes,it's my mistake.I have done the code perfect.The image I am downloading has a padding on every side and I am thinking that it was spacing there.

Answer (score 0):

`layout_width="fill_parent"` will produce extra space based on the width of column.

eq: if gridview with = 440dp and your columnWidth=100dp, then 40dp extra space is there. It will be distributed between your columns.

So,
either you may need to use `layout_width="wrap_content"

or you may need to set columnwidth dynamically based on the width of the gridview

or set item width to wrap_content and calculate numColumns dynamically